# How to limit VRAM usage for Blender?

Tags: hardware

I have a computer at home with a GTX 1060, and an i5-4460. I use this computer for most of my rendering and 3D modelling. My school issues Chromebooks, which obviously I can't use Blender on. My solution is to use a *VNC server* on my main computer that I can access from my school Chromebook, so I can work on Blender projects during school. One problem I have is when rendering with GPU, sometimes my VNC server will crash, and I have to physically restart my computer for it to work again. I believe this is because Blender is using too many resources. Is there a way to limit the amount of VRAM blender uses?

Comment: The only way is to run Blender in virtual system environment and limit VRAM or other hardware resources there. If it crashes, you will have to reboot that virtual machine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Q:** Is there a way to limit the amount of VRAM blender uses?

**A:** NO

*Example:* if your scene need 2GB of VRAM, Blender need 2GB VRAM for render this scene. No other way. Imagine, you want to pour 2l water into 1.5l bottle.

Also there are no direct evidence the problem is amount of VRAM.
I don't thing VNC need VRAM for running. This doesn't make sense:-)

Comment: Blender can shut down the display driver and that indeed can effect other programs. So VNC might crash. But I agree more investigation is needed.

Comment: I wrote: "I don't thing VNC need VRAM for running", because you mentioned VNC, so I suppose everything run OK without VNC. If Blender crash also without VNC, VNC is absolutely irrelevant, so you had no reason to mentioned it  :-) Anyway, in CUDA: Out of memory error, Blender stop rendering, doesn't not crash or freeze PC. Some error message should be helpful:-)

Comment: @Shubol3D Hmm.. It could be something other than VRAM. All I know is when rendering certain scenes on GPU my VNC crashes.